# Leanback VerticalGridFragment remove top spacing

Tags: android, android-layout, leanback

I am using VerticalGridFragment to display items in a grid-like layout
I don't need to show search or title and I want the rows to start from top of the screen without any margins. Any help?[image: example in the image below]

Comment: Could you show the screen shot please.

Comment: @jaydroider I edited my question, check the screenshot

Comment: You mean you want to move this rows to just below top section right ?

Comment: yes, i was able to remove the titleview section and give it height=0,
but i still can't figure out a way to move the rows up

Comment: Could you tell me this is the full screen which you provided or you have left side items also connected with rows ? or simply you have this much rows only in *Browse Fragment*.

Comment: this is fullscreen, i want items to be coming from bottom of the screen,
nothing on the left, i don't need the headers, I disabled them

Comment: the concept is for a TV channel list, when the user presses OK button, he will see this menu with his channel list, the reason why i need it like this, is for better user experience (not covering the TV area, he can still watch TV while going through channel list)

Comment: Follow my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Have you tried my answer ? have you get it working or not ? Let me know if you face any issue or have any doubt related to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need create new class with name CustomVerticalGridPresenter and put followig code in it[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY)

```
public class CustomVerticalGridPresenter extends VerticalGridPresenter {

    VerticalGridView gridView;

    CustomVerticalGridPresenter(int zoom, boolean val){
        super(zoom, val);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeGridViewHolder(ViewHolder vh) {
        super.initializeGridViewHolder(vh);
        gridView = vh.getGridView();
        int top = 20;//this is the new value for top padding
        int bottom = gridView.getPaddingBottom();
        int right = gridView.getPaddingRight();
        int left = gridView.getPaddingLeft();
        gridView.setPadding(left,top,right,bottom);
    }
}
```

Then in verticalgridfragment class use

```
CustomVerticalGridPresenter videoGridPresenter = new 
CustomVerticalGridPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR, false);
```

instead of

```
VerticalGridPresentervideoGridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR, false);
```

Answer (score 14):

I found a way to do it by overriding the **VerticalGridPresenter** of the **VerticalGridFragment** then getting the **VerticalGridView**, and setting top padding to a smaller value.
In the **CustomVerticalGridPresenter** class (that extends **VerticalGridPresenter**), override this method:

```
@Override
protected void initializeGridViewHolder(ViewHolder vh) {
    super.initializeGridViewHolder(vh);
    gridView = vh.getGridView();
    int top= 20;//this is the new value for top padding
    int bottom = gridView.getPaddingBottom();
    int right = gridView.getPaddingRight();
    int left = gridView.getPaddingLeft();
    gridView.setPadding(left,top,right,bottom);
}
```

Then in the VerticalGridFragment, assign the new CustomVerticalGridPresenter as following:

```
 CustomVerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new CustomVerticalGridPresenter();
    gridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(NUM_COLUMNS);
    setGridPresenter(gridPresenter);
```

Comment: yes it works. but you need to explain your answer in better way.

Answer (score 4):

Another way over this problem is to set the windowAlignment attributes of the VerticalGridView. Most notably ...

```
verticalGridView.windowAlignment = BaseGridView.WINDOW_ALIGN_LOW_EDGE //this will remove the top margin
verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffset = 0
verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent = 25f //find correct values for your case
```

Answer (score 2):

> `First of follow this steps to move the rows up which is by default given margins by Lean back Library`.

`1. Go to you SDK`.

`2. Inside SDK -> extras -> android -> support -> v17 -> leanback -> res -> values.`

`3. Inside values folder copy the dimens.xml inside your current project and copy to your projects res -> values folder`.

> `Now you have the file name dimens.xml inside your values folder`.
>
> `Now open the dimens.xml file which you have copied`.

`Change the value for property defined below. By default it will given 168dp around that. So make it less to decrease the top margin as i have given below.`

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_top">35dp</dimen>
```

**Now you can be able to split your rows up exact below of top section of your** `Browse Fragment`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am trying to do as explained, I am getting Resource not found error as following:

  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v17.leanback.widget.TitleView

Comment: @nadine87 Can you please edit your question and add this full *Logcat* information in above question and also mention what changes you made and raised this exception. Because this *dimen* file is not using any resources. you have something else mismatch.

Comment: It's not, it should be using leanback layouts, I didn't make any changes,
i just added the dimens file to res/values and I edited it to add my custom dimen values,
the projects run then a runtime exception occurs.
I can't copy logcat, it's too long to be fitted here

Note: there a 2 similar errors (Error inflating class android.support.v17.leanback.widget.TitleView and SearchOrbView)

Comment: @nadine87 Yes it should use `Lean back layouts` that's why i have mentioned that above exception is not because of *dimen* file but because of something else. `dimen` files are just using the *values in dp* for all layouts which are provided by *leanback*. And i have the same issue of displaying row from top i have solved it by changing only dp values in dimen file nothing else.

Comment: this solution could help, but it didn't work with me, I found the right solution, please check my next answer

Comment: it works for browse fragment not for verticalgrid fragment

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a theme and set it for your Activity / Fragment.

In **themes.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Leanback.NoTitle" parent="Theme.Leanback.Browse">
    <item name="browseRowsMarginTop">@dimen/lb_browse_rows_margin_top_none</item>>
</style>
```

in **dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_top_none">32dp</dimen>
```